# Error while using google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am geting following error while using google map api. I am running my application on localhost so I did not register it on google map. I have also searched some other solutions and try them all but still getting the same.

```
This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError
```

Here is my code.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUX7v9haBCA7Gv_YD9hEhj1m1nMBiZfqY&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div class="row" id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;">          </div>
```

PS: I have to implement a functionality in which if we select a city like california than map start to point out that city(california). So, if possible also tell me some solution of these.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says "... or this site is not authorized to use it". You can't use API KEY on localhost. Instead, for localhost use Google Maps Api without API KEY:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```